# Default empty usage of methods of uninstantiated class

Tags: c++, design-patterns

In my system I have many callbacks which contains calling for method of classes, that are not instantiated according to some configurations values, and when they are not initalized I want the calling to them to do nothing, instead of rasing a seg fault.
For example I have some InitManager class that in it's constructor we have:

```
if (config.is_connected) { std::shared<CloudClient> cloud_client = std::make_shared<CLoudCLient>(); }
```

And in the InitManager I have a callback of some event coming from another process, which includes the following:

```
...
cloud_client->saveData();
...
cloud_client->notifyUser();
...
```

So my current solution is before every method use to do:

```
...
if (cloud_client) {
    cloud_client->saveData();
}
...
if (cloud_client) {
   cloud_client->notifyUser();
}
...
```

It keeps my wanted behaviour. The problem is that whenever another developer adds a new method, or uses an old one he might not check if the cloud_client exists, and we will figure it out only by tests when checking with that specific configuration. And in addition my solution makes the code less redable because it contain many if conditions.
If anyone have some design solution which will enable me to do:

```
cloud_client->notifyUser();
```

without the if condition every time and just do nothing when cloud client does not exists. Or even just make every use of this class's methods fail in compilation if developer didn't use the

```
 `if (cloud_client)`
```

it will be great!

Comment: I can't get my head around this.  Please post a [mre] to demonstrate what you mean.

Comment: @PaulSanders Thanks, I've edited my question :) Hope it better explains my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you, OP, for editing your question.  You have done a good job, the issue is now clear.

I would suggest a 'wrapper' class for `CloudClient` - let's call it `CloudClientWrapper`, which holds a pointer to a `CloudClient` instance (which might be `nullptr`) as a member variable.  `CloudClientWrapper` can then be responsible for testing whether that variable is `nullptr`, which means that callers don't need to worry about it.

To prevent external code from calling `CloudClient` methods directly, declare them `private` and make `CloudClientWrapper` a `friend` of `CloudClient`.

So, something like this:

```
class CloudClient
{
friend class CloudClientWrapper;

private:
    void Foo ();
    void Bar ();
    // ...
};

class CloudClientWrapper
{
public:
    CloudClientWrapper (CloudClient *client) : m_client (client) { }
    
    void Foo () { if (m_client) m_client->Foo (); }
    void Bar () { if (m_client) m_client->Bar (); }
    // ....
    
private:
    CloudClient *m_client;
};
```

Your methods can take parameters and have return types, of course.  `CouldClientWrapper` just needs to pass them on.  It might be a lot of boilerplate, but I don't see a better way.

Implementing `CloudClientWrapper` entirely in a header file might have some performance advantages, by the way.  It makes it easy for the compiler to inline the code.  There is such a thing as link time optimisation (LTO), which aims to do the same thing, but, in my experience, it slows down link times and generates a bunch of huge intermediate build products (I have given up on it).

Comment: Thanks! It's very good solution! It does answers my needs